# Latex preview on question title?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, titles, markdown-preview

Almost every single time I type a question I end up having to go back and edit the title due to no latex preview. Obviously you can write the title in the body first to check it but it's very easy to forget to do that and it entails you then having to copy and paste it into the title bar. And that could hardly be considered good UX practise in 2015...having to preview something in a different textbox before copy-pasting into another one...

So why not have latex previewing on titles as well as bodies?

Comment: When editing, I have MathJax preview for titles too. Is it only when first asking the questions, or do you also have no preview when editing?

Comment: I see it works for editing yes. But surely it should also be enabled for first asking the question too?

Comment: Ah, I see. When writing the question, you have no title preview at all. Seems rather inconvenient. I agree, that should be enabled from the start.

Comment: @DanielFischer Where do you find the rendered title preview when editing? I seem not to have it, but I'm probably blind...

Comment: Feature request at meta.SE (3 years old, score 25): [Please include the title in the question preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115247/please-include-the-title-in-the-question-preview)

Comment: @DanielR At the top of the page, above the title editing box. The title is displayed normally, but it updates when you edit it, including MathJax rendering.

Comment: @DanielFischer How odd. When [editing](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1232772/edit), I get [this appearance](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ev2zn.png). Still can't find that preview. :(

Comment: @DanielR There is a privilege (I think 10k) that allows you to edit posts inline. When you have enough reputation you get what Daniel Fischer sees, when you don't you get what you see. (It's supposed to make editing easier for high rep users. TBH I've never understood why editing should be harder for low rep users, but whatever).

Comment: @DanielFischer See above. You can try editing a question on a site where you don't have enough rep, you should see what Daniel R sees.

Comment: Thanks @NajibIdrissi, that makes sense (your explanation that is; the behavior of the site, not so much).

Comment: @DanielR It's pretty much like Najib says, it seems. However, I also get the title preview on [meta.se] where I have less than 10k, so maybe it's the editing privilege (2k) that triggers the change, or the settings on [meta.se] are different.

Comment: This should be changed to also allow low-rep users to see the title preview. Not so much for the convenience of having MathJax preview, but to make the title more visible to the editors, which will probably make them more prone to improving the title while editing the body.

Comment: I was about to post this as a question on meta again (2019). It seems that consensus was reached in 2015, as of 2019 it's still an issue. What is the problem? Is there a way to contribute here?

Comment: I made a new post on [meta.se] pointing out that this is problem mainly on MathJax-enabled sites: [Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361217).