# Editing a post does not show the edited title

Tags: feature-request, editing, suggested-edits, titles, markdown-preview

When I edit a question, a preview of the edited content is shown, which makes it easy to know if I'm doing this right.

But: when editing the title of a question (e.g. replacing "Z" by "$\mathbb{Z}$") does not show a preview of the edited title, which makes it difficult to judge whether or not my title edits are correct. (In fact, I copy the edited title temporary into the content)

Is is possible to preview edited title while editing a question and is this the appropriate place for such a question or is it a more general meta StackExchange question?

It seems that KReiser does not understand my issue: I'm not talking about viewing the edits, after they are finished: I'm talking about doing the actual edit.

Here an extra example:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, I am adding $\mathbb{Z}$ to the title.
In region 1, there is the title I'm editing.
In region 2, there is the question's content I'm editing.
In region 3, there is the preview of the question's content.

I don't see the preview of the edited title.

Comment: This has been asked on the main meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361217/196432) and here (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25252/42969, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20248/42969), unfortunately without any reponse.

Comment: @MartinR. You are more or less right, but apparently there's a more general question to refer to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361217/show-a-preview-of-the-title-when-editing-asking-at-least-on-the-mathjax-sites. Unfortunately, as this question is not on this particular site, I can't use it as a duplicate subject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latex preview on question title?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20248/latex-preview-on-question-title)

Comment: Thanks for linking to my feature request: [Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361217). On [meta.se], there is also this one: [Please include the title in the question preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115247).

Comment: So it seems that you are talking specifically about *[suggested edits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/suggested-edits/info)*. The preview in KReiser's post shows edit by a user who has [full editing privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) and doesn't need the edit to be reviewed. (So I have added the tag ([meta-tag:suggested-edits]) and I have retract my close vote, since it doesn't seem to be an exact duplicate.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid I don't understand your question - when I attempt to edit titles, I see a preview which shows the edits made to the title and includes MathJax:

[image: a screenshot of the meta post being edited, with "Yes it does, with $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of Z" added to the title and rendered at the top of the page]

Does your edit screen look different? If so, could you post a screenshot of what you see in your question so we're all on the same page?

Comment: There are two possibilities: either there's a misunderstanding or your computer behaves differently than mine. I'm working with Google Chrome, I'm surfing incognito (or InPrivate) and my computer is a Windows-10 one. I've added a screenshot of my screen to my question).

Comment: The difference is that you @Dominique can only make edit *suggestions* which must be approved by other users, whereas KReiser has the [Edit posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege and can edit any question or answer right away.