# Why not add the title of the question in the preview while writing it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, titles, markdown-preview

Sometimes I don't know if the $\LaTeX$ used in the title of a question I'm writing is correct. Why is not added the title preview of the question when one is writing it to avoid typos? Just like it's done with the body of the question.

Comment: Older similar post: [Latex preview on question title?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20248)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I will read it.

Comment: And also a feature request on meta.SE: [Please include the title in the question preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115247)

Comment: Agree. I always have to type it in the input box to see the preview then cut it onto the title bar.

Comment: I agree with this request. It should be added. I might not particularly use it, but I can see the purpose behind it.

Comment: I made a new post on [meta.se] pointing out that this is problem mainly on MathJax-enabled sites: [Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361217).